# Compile Time & Run Time Error

Tags: java

```
class Dims {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = {{1,2,}, {3,4}};
        int[] b = (int[]) a[1];
        Object o1 = a;
        int[][] a2 = (int[][]) o1;
        int[] b2 = (int[]) o1;   // Line 7
        System.out.println(b[1]);
    } 
}
```

I have a doubt in the above piece of code in Java.
Why does it give a Runtime Exception and not a compile time error at line number 7?

Comment: You have a question, or your homework assignment has a question?

Comment: This is one of the questions in a Java Book that I am reading. The book also has the solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because o1 is an int[][], not an int[]. The RuntimeException you get is a ClassCastException, because the first is an array of int arrays, and the latter just an array of ints.

You don't get a compile time error, because o1 is defined as an Object. So at compile time, it could hold anything that is derived from object, which is in fact every Type in Java except the primitive types long, int, short, byte, char, double, float and boolean. So, at compile time it seems possible that the object might in fact be an int[].

Answer (score 3):

You can't just convert a two-dimensional array to a one-dimensional array by casting.  You need to copy the values over to a new one-dimensional array in some fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you don't use a cast, the compiler can determine whether the usage is valid.  If you use a cast, you are telling the compiler you know what you are doing and it has to use a different type for the reference.

```
int[][] a = {{1, 2,}, {3, 4}};
int[] b = a[1]; // no cast is used here and the compiler can tell this is valid.
Object o1 = a;
int[][] a2 = (int[][]) o1; // This cast is fine.
int[] b2 = (int[]) o1;   // My IDE warns this case may produce a ClassCastException.
System.out.println(b[1]);
```